# Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be a $k$-cycle, $k>1$. Show that $\sigma^j$ (where $j$ is an integer) is a cycle if and only if $j$ is coprime with $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a $k$-cycle, $k>1$. Show that $\sigma^j$ (where $j$ is an integer) is a cycle if and only if $j$ is coprime with $k$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You're much more likely to get a helpful answer if you write a few sentences explaining how you have thought about this problem and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

If $j$ and $k$ are NOT coprime, then $\mathrm{gcd}(j,k) = \ell > 1$. Write $\sigma$ in cycle notation as $(i_0 i_1 \dots i_{k-1})$. Now look at the orbit of $i_0$ under $\sigma^j$. It will consist of $i_0, i_j, i_{2j}, i_{3j}, \dots$, etc..., where the subscripts $j$, $2j$, $3j$, etc... are taken mod $k$. But since $\mathrm{lcm}(j,k) = \frac{jk}{\mathrm{gcd}(j,k)} = \left( \frac{k}{\ell}\right) j$, you see that $\left(\frac{k}{\ell}\right)j \equiv 0$ mod $k$. This means that $\sigma^{k/\ell}(i_0) = i_0$, and so the orbit of $i_0$ under $\sigma^j$ has size $\frac{k}{\ell} < k$. This shows that $\sigma^j$ is NOT a $k$-cycle, since it breaks into smaller disjoint cycles.

Now you just need to prove the converse: that if $j$ and $k$ ARE coprime, then this cannot happen. Or, equivalently, you could prove that IF this happens (if $\sigma^j$ breaks into smaller disjoint cycles), then $j$ and $k$ must have a common factor (namely the number of orbits of $\sigma^j$).